# Is it possible to prevent type casting for deserialize method of JMSSerializer?

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I need prevent type casting because I am validating entity after deserializing it

For example If I deserialize following json it will create entity with sort order 5. I am using this validation for my api and I don't give incorrect error messages.

```
{"sort_order":"5aaa"} ==> Sort Order will be 5
{"sort_order":"aaa"} ==> Sort Order will be 0
```

Is there a way to prevent type casting?